# Ok to rebase git feature branches that have been pushed only for backup purposes?

Tags: git

I've read that rebasing local feature branches that have already been pushed to a remote can cause problems, and I believe I understand why. However, some of the use cases for git rebase seem to correspond to long-running feature branches. Perhaps I'm more paranoid than most, but I can't imagine developing a non-trivial feature branch without pushing to origin at least once, if only for the purpose of backing up my work. In such cases, though my forked repo is public on Github, I'm not collaborating on the feature with anyone, and it's extremely unlikely anyone would pull the feature branch before it's ready for merge (and even less likely I'd want to merge back from someone who did). Can I safely assume that the caveat regarding "published" feature branches is not meant to apply to this use case, but only to the case in which you push the branch for the purpose of allowing others to collaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note, the extremely simple (simplistic?) rule of thumb is "never rebase a published branch", since someone else might be using it.

This rule is, in my opinion, *too* simple.  As you note, maybe no one else is using it!  In which case, rebasing—copying some number of commits to a new chain, and making the name point to the new branch tip—is fine.

Even that doesn't really cover everything, though.  The rule I use is this: ***Rebasing a branch is OK if everyone using the branch agrees that it's OK.***  Note that this covers all three cases:

- The branch is not published.  You're the only one using it; you rebase it; you have automatically agreed that this is OK, so everyone using it agrees.
- The branch *is* published, but you're the only one using it.  This devolves to the previous case.
- The branch is published and several people use it.  Do they all agree that it may be rebased?  Then it may be rebased!